# Accidentally my database table droped from xampp server. how can I recover mysql table from xampp server?

Tags: mysql, xampp, data-recovery

Accidentally dropped a table from my MySQL XAMPP server.

How can I recover that table?

Comment: Do you have a backup or export of the sql script?

Comment: I don't have any backup of those database.

Comment: You have a big problem in this case, I'm not sure it's possible to recover the datas.... You have no script at all?

Comment: I have no any script.